# Vertical Align Images in SlickCarousel

Tags: php, css, mysql, image, vertical-alignment

I've recently started a new job at an Audio Visual company and they've asked me to develop an application that allows users (without authentication) to upload images to a display page and have it automatically scroll through.

I chose the only carousel I've ever found helpful but my issue is that the landscape images are not vertically aligned with the portrait images.

My code is set up so that the uploaded image is sent through to a database and then retrieved to display automatically in the carousel so each image has it's own individual div tag.

The page itself won't load without database connection and doesn't work in JSFiddle because of the PHP elements within.
Also here are screenshots of my issue:
[Image 1 displaying portrait image at full height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkmaB.png)
[Image 2 displaying landscape image at top of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63WdC.png)

I want image 2 to display in the center of the page and everywhere I look for the correct information I don't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Please help me, I would very much appreciate it!
AlexJamesDean.

Comment: JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/5yjswj4k/

Comment: have you checked settings provided in http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I have looked into this but I don't see anything directly relating to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add position to image div

```
.autoplay{position: relative;}
#img_div {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
   postion: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transfrom: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This seems to help a bit, but now the top portion of the images is hidden.
http://imgur.com/a/EMeXd